# Bot has roblem with sending/editing embed messages

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js, send, defined

So i already asked around here and there but i dont find out how to fix eroor: ReferenceError: `send is not defined` In the non embed version everything works fine but here it just won't.

```
module.exports = {
        name: 'lat2',
        description: 'Let the Bot display latency/Response Time and API latency/"Remote Response time"',
        execute(message, args) {
            const Discord = require('discord.js');
            let Embed1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor(0x0099ff)
                .setDescription("Pinging...")

            let Embed2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor(0x0099ff)
                .setTitle("Latencies")
                .setDescription(`Latency/Response Time: ${send.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp}ms\nAPI latency/"Remote Response time": ${Math.round(message.client.ws.ping)}ms`)

            msg.channel.send(Embed1).then(msg => {
                msg.edit(Embed2);
            });
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't sending the message, it's complaining about the `${send.createdTimestamp}`, because you didn't define "send" anywhere there.
Try replacing it with `message.createdAt`

To still get the Latency, try this:

```js
module.exports = {
        name: 'lat2',
        description: 'Let the Bot display latency/Response Time and API latency/"Remote Response time"',
        execute(message, args) {
            const Discord = require('discord.js');
            let Embed1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor(0x0099ff)
                .setDescription("Pinging...")

            msg.channel.send(Embed1).then(m => {

            let Embed2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor(0x0099ff)
                .setTitle("Latencies")
                .setDescription(`Latency/Response Time: ${m.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp}ms\nAPI latency/"Remote Response time": ${Math.round(message.client.ws.ping)}ms`)
                m.edit(Embed2);
            });
        }
    };
```

Comment: You were right thanks a lot, but do you know anything else than message.createdAt because then it would be 0ms

Comment: You can only get the latency after you edited it, so you'd have to define the second embed in the section where you edit the message. I edited my answer to show what I mean